# Broadcom problems in 16.04.1

Tags: broadcom

I have no wifi connections on a 13" MacBook Pro (mid 2010). I was trying out Ubuntu (no install). All solutions I have seen so far require a network connection which I don't have (except wifi when it works). Are Broadcom cards still broken in 16.04.1? Are there other solutions I didn't see?

Comment: There are offline guides for both `wl` and `b43` drivers.

Comment: Broadcom cards are not broken in any recent Ubuntu version. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers